# Closing Pop Up by clicking outside Jquery Why this is not working

Tags: jquery, css

Jquery Code

```
$(function() {
        //----- OPEN
        $(".abcd").on('click', function(e)  {
            $(".popup").fadeIn(350);
             e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
     $("body").click(function(){
      $(".popup").fadeOut(350);
    });

    // Prevent events from getting pass .popup
    $(".abcd").click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    });
```

Popup is inside this class

```
<div class="popup" >
</div>
```

Popup Called when clicking

```
<li><a class = "abcd" href="#">Login</a></li>
```

CSS

```
/* Outer */
.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    tabindex="-1";
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background-color:#000000;
    background: url(../images/home-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover; 
    z-index: 99 !important;
}

/* Inner */
.popup-inner {
    max-width:700px;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

1. Above code is closing popup when clicked anywhere but it should
    close when clicked outside. 
 2. How this can be handled please help.?

Please point what i am doing wrong.
Refer
http://jsfiddle.net/ukwx5eLh/

Comment: Explain more what is working? And what is not working? And add a fiddler.

Comment: Pop up is coming up but on clicking anywhere inside or outside it disappear . How to fix this so that it disappear only when click outside ?

Comment: Check my answer! fixed the issue..

Comment: Hello,Check my answer it is solved your issue....you need to change class popup-inner to prevent pass popup in jquery and in jsfiddle you have to add popup-inner div after popup and remove position fixed from logmod class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this for clicking outside closing popup

```
$(".popup-inner").click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```js
$(function() {
  //----- OPEN
  $(".abcd").on('click', function(e) {
    $(".popup").fadeIn(350);
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("body").click(function() {
    $(".popup").fadeOut(350);
  });

  // Prevent events from getting pass .popup
  $(".popup-inner").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```css
/* Outer */

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background-color: #000000;
  background: url(https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 99 !important;
}


/* Inner */

.popup-inner {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-inner">
    hi
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li><a class="abcd" href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you wrote it like that, I think jQuery is just weird with this stuff.

You could simplify it into one click listener:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var clickedTrigger = e.target.id === 'abcd';
    clickedTrigger ? $('.popup').fadeIn(350) : $('.popup').fadeOut(350);
})
```

Comment: Yes, it's just a quick and dirty way of writing it.

Comment: Here, this is working now: http://jsfiddle.net/ukwx5eLh/4/

I updated my code in my original comment too.

Comment: Clicking on popup also led to closing of popup please correct that also

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(function() {
  //----- OPEN
  $(".abcd").on('click', function() {
    $(".popup").fadeIn(350);
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $(".popup").fadeOut(350);
  });

  $('.logmod__container').on('click', function() {
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.logmod {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.logmod::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.logmod__wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 550px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 120px auto;
}

.logmod__close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  background: url("http://imgh.us/close_white.svg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: -72px;
  margin-right: -24px;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

.logmod__container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.logmod__container::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.logmod__tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.logmod__tab-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logmod__tab.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}

.logmod__tabs {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.logmod__tabs::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.logmod__tabs li.current a {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
}

.logmod__tabs li a {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background: #D2D8D8;
  line-height: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #809191;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logmod__tabs li a:focus {
  outline: dotted 1px;
}

.logmod__heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
}

.logmod__heading-subtitle {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #888;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.logmod__form {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.logmod__alter {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.logmod__alter::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.logmod__alter .connect:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.connect {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  line-height: 72px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.connect::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.connect:focus,
.connect:hover,
.connect:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.connect__icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.connect__context {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.connect.facebook {
  background: #3b5998;
  color: #FFF;
}

.connect.facebook a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.connect.facebook .connect__icon {
  background: #283d68;
}

.connect.googleplus {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: #FFF;
}

.connect.googleplus a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.connect.googleplus .connect__icon {
  background: #b52f1f;
}

.simform {
  position: relative;
}

.simform__actions {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.simform__actions::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.simform__actions .sumbit {
  height: 48px;
  float: right;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 50%;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.simform__actions .sumbit::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.simform__actions-sidetext {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 9px 0 0 0;
  color: #8C979E;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.simform__actions-sidetext::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.sminputs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.sminputs::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.sminputs .input {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 71px;
  padding: 11px 24px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: none;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.sminputs .input.active {
  background: #eee;
}

.sminputs .input.active .hide-password {
  background: #eee;
}

.sminputs .input.full {
  width: 100%;
}

.sminputs .input label {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.sminputs .input input {
  postion: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 19.2px;
  color: #555;
  border-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(75, 89, 102, 0.85);
}

.sminputs .hide-password {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 12px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.btn,
.simform__actions .sumbit {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-shadow: none;
  min-width: 90px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
}

.btn.full,
.simform__actions .full.sumbit {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn.lg,
.simform__actions .lg.sumbit {
  min-width: 125px;
  padding: 17px 14px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.btn.sm,
.simform__actions .sm.sumbit {
  min-width: 65px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.btn.xs,
.simform__actions .xs.sumbit {
  min-width: 45px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.btn.circle,
.simform__actions .circle.sumbit {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  min-width: 56px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.btn.circle.lg,
.simform__actions .circle.lg.sumbit {
  width: 78px;
  height: 78px;
  min-width: 78px;
}

.btn.circle.sm,
.simform__actions .circle.sm.sumbit {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
}

.btn.circle.xs,
.simform__actions .circle.xs.sumbit {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

.btn:focus,
.simform__actions .sumbit:focus,
.btn:active,
.simform__actions .sumbit:active,
.btn.active,
.simform__actions .active.sumbit,
.btn:active:focus,
.simform__actions .sumbit:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.simform__actions .active.sumbit:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn.red,
.simform__actions .red.sumbit {
  background: #f44336;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.red:active,
.simform__actions .red.sumbit:active,
.btn.red:focus,
.simform__actions .red.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #ef1d0d;
}

.btn.red:hover,
.simform__actions .red.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #f32c1e;
}

.btn.pink,
.simform__actions .pink.sumbit {
  background: #E91E63;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.pink:active,
.simform__actions .pink.sumbit:active,
.btn.pink:focus,
.simform__actions .pink.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #c61350;
}

.btn.pink:hover,
.simform__actions .pink.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #d81558;
}

.btn.purple,
.simform__actions .purple.sumbit {
  background: #9C27B0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.purple:active,
.simform__actions .purple.sumbit:active,
.btn.purple:focus,
.simform__actions .purple.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #7b1f8a;
}

.btn.purple:hover,
.simform__actions .purple.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #89229b;
}

.btn.deep-purple,
.simform__actions .deep-purple.sumbit {
  background: #673AB7;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.deep-purple:active,
.simform__actions .deep-purple.sumbit:active,
.btn.deep-purple:focus,
.simform__actions .deep-purple.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #532f94;
}

.btn.deep-purple:hover,
.simform__actions .deep-purple.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #5c34a4;
}

.btn.indigo,
.simform__actions .indigo.sumbit {
  background: #3F51B5;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.indigo:active,
.simform__actions .indigo.sumbit:active,
.btn.indigo:focus,
.simform__actions .indigo.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #334293;
}

.btn.indigo:hover,
.simform__actions .indigo.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #3849a2;
}

.btn.blue,
.simform__actions .blue.sumbit {
  background: #2196F3;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.blue:active,
.simform__actions .blue.sumbit:active,
.btn.blue:focus,
.simform__actions .blue.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #0c7fda;
}

.btn.blue:hover,
.simform__actions .blue.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #0d8aee;
}

.btn.light-blue,
.simform__actions .light-blue.sumbit {
  background: #03A9F4;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.light-blue:active,
.simform__actions .light-blue.sumbit:active,
.btn.light-blue:focus,
.simform__actions .light-blue.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #028ac7;
}

.btn.light-blue:hover,
.simform__actions .light-blue.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #0398db;
}

.btn.cyan,
.simform__actions .cyan.sumbit {
  background: #00BCD4;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.cyan:active,
.simform__actions .cyan.sumbit:active,
.btn.cyan:focus,
.simform__actions .cyan.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #0093a6;
}

.btn.cyan:hover,
.simform__actions .cyan.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #00a5bb;
}

.btn.teal,
.simform__actions .teal.sumbit {
  background: #009688;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.teal:active,
.simform__actions .teal.sumbit:active,
.btn.teal:focus,
.simform__actions .teal.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #00685e;
}

.btn.teal:hover,
.simform__actions .teal.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #007d71;
}

.btn.green,
.simform__actions .green.sumbit {
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.green:active,
.simform__actions .green.sumbit:active,
.btn.green:focus,
.simform__actions .green.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #3e8f41;
}

.btn.green:hover,
.simform__actions .green.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #449d48;
}

.btn.light-green,
.simform__actions .light-green.sumbit {
  background: #8BC34A;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.light-green:active,
.simform__actions .light-green.sumbit:active,
.btn.light-green:focus,
.simform__actions .light-green.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #74a838;
}

.btn.light-green:hover,
.simform__actions .light-green.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #7eb73d;
}

.btn.lime,
.simform__actions .lime.sumbit {
  background: #CDDC39;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.lime:active,
.simform__actions .lime.sumbit:active,
.btn.lime:focus,
.simform__actions .lime.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #b6c423;
}

.btn.lime:hover,
.simform__actions .lime.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #c6d626;
}

.btn.yellow,
.simform__actions .yellow.sumbit {
  background: #FFEB3B;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.yellow:active,
.simform__actions .yellow.sumbit:active,
.btn.yellow:focus,
.simform__actions .yellow.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #ffe60d;
}

.btn.yellow:hover,
.simform__actions .yellow.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #ffe822;
}

.btn.amber,
.simform__actions .amber.sumbit {
  background: #FFC107;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.amber:active,
.simform__actions .amber.sumbit:active,
.btn.amber:focus,
.simform__actions .amber.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #d8a200;
}

.btn.amber:hover,
.simform__actions .amber.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #edb100;
}

.btn.orange,
.simform__actions .orange.sumbit {
  background: #FF9800;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.orange:active,
.simform__actions .orange.sumbit:active,
.btn.orange:focus,
.simform__actions .orange.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #d17d00;
}

.btn.orange:hover,
.simform__actions .orange.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #e68900;
}

.btn.deep-orange,
.simform__actions .deep-orange.sumbit {
  background: #FF5722;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.deep-orange:active,
.simform__actions .deep-orange.sumbit:active,
.btn.deep-orange:focus,
.simform__actions .deep-orange.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #f33a00;
}

.btn.deep-orange:hover,
.simform__actions .deep-orange.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #ff4409;
}

.btn.brown,
.simform__actions .brown.sumbit {
  background: #795548;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.brown:active,
.simform__actions .brown.sumbit:active,
.btn.brown:focus,
.simform__actions .brown.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #5c4137;
}

.btn.brown:hover,
.simform__actions .brown.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #694a3e;
}

.btn.grey,
.simform__actions .grey.sumbit {
  background: #9E9E9E;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.grey:active,
.simform__actions .grey.sumbit:active,
.btn.grey:focus,
.simform__actions .grey.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #878787;
}

.btn.grey:hover,
.simform__actions .grey.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #919191;
}

.btn.blue-grey,
.simform__actions .blue-grey.sumbit {
  background: #607D8B;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn.blue-grey:active,
.simform__actions .blue-grey.sumbit:active,
.btn.blue-grey:focus,
.simform__actions .blue-grey.sumbit:focus {
  background-color: #4d6570;
}

.btn.blue-grey:hover,
.simform__actions .blue-grey.sumbit:hover {
  background-color: #566f7c;
}

.special {
  color: #f44336;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}

.special:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  background: #f00;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.special:hover {
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}

.special:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#baseline {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  background-image: url(https://basehold.it/i/24);
}


/* Outer */

.popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  tabindex="-1";
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background-color: #000000;
  background: url(../images/home-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 99 !important;
}


/* Inner */

.popup-inner {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
}


/* Close Button */

.popup-close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: ease 0.25s all;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.popup-close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="abcd" href="#">Login</a>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="logmod">
      <div class="logmod__wrapper">
        <span class="logmod__close">Close</span>
        <div class="logmod__container">
          <ul class="logmod__tabs">
            <li data-tabtar="lgm-2"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li data-tabtar="lgm-1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="logmod__tab-wrapper">
            <div class="logmod__tab lgm-1">
              <div class="logmod__heading">
                <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your personal details <strong>to create an acount</strong></span>
              </div>
              <div class="logmod__form">
                <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                  <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input full">
                      <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                      <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input string optional">
                      <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                      <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="text" size="50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input string optional">
                      <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
                      <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="simform__actions">
                    <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Create Account" />
                    <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms & Privacy</a></span>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="logmod__alter">
                <div class="logmod__alter-container">
                  <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                      <span>Create an account with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
                    </div>
                  </a>

                  <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                      <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                      <span>Create an account with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="logmod__tab lgm-2">
              <div class="logmod__heading">
                <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your email and password <strong>to sign in</strong></span>
              </div>
              <div class="logmod__form">
                <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                  <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input full">
                      <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                      <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sminputs">
                    <div class="input full">
                      <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                      <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50" />
                      <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="simform__actions">
                    <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Log In" />
                    <span class="simform__actions-sidetext"><a class="special" role="link" href="#">Forgot your password?<br>Click here</a></span>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="logmod__alter">
                <div class="logmod__alter-container">
                  <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                      <span>Sign in with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                    <div class="connect__icon">
                      <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connect__context">
                      <span>Sign in with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
                    </div>

                  </a>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Instead of targetting body target document.

It is good practice to use `return false` instead of `e.stopPropagation();`

> You can read about why not to use e.stopPropagation()? And what damage it can cause in your DOM [here](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)

I used my own CSS styling feel free to use yours. Hope this fixes your issue. If you found any issue comment so that I can fix that as well.

EDIT: I think this is what you wanted. If any issue comment below.

Comment: If i am clicking in popup popup is disappearing please check

Comment: My bad fixed it.

Comment: Can you help in one more thing.I have set a bg image for Remaining space out of popup. Can this cause a problem? Because i am using same code it is not working there?

Comment: Can mark only one as above marked is also working. Thanks